# getting incorrect output for area of square and hexagon

Tags: python, math

I have been learning if, else, and elif statements in my python class and we have to do a project where you are required to put in one of three shapes. The shape options are circle, square, and hexagon. We have to be able to correctly find the area and the perimeter of the chosen shape and print it. The output should match a real world example that is given to us. My code:

```
if (shape == "circle" or "Circle"):
    circumf = float(input("Please provide the circumference: "))
    areaCircle = math.pi * circumf ** 2
    perimCircle = 2 * math.pi * circumf
    print("{:^14}{:^14}{:^14}{:^14}".format("Shape", "Value", "Area", "Perimeter"))
    print("{:^14}{:^14.2f}{:^14.2f}{:^14.2f}".format(shape, circumf, areaCircle, perimCircle))
elif (shape == "square" or "Square"):
    sideSquare = float(input("Please provide the side length: "))
    areaSquare = sideSquare ** 2
    perimSquare = 4 * areaSquare
    print("{:^14}{:^14}{:^14}{:^14}".format("Shape", "Value", "Area", "Perimeter"))
    print("{:^14}{:^14.2f}{:^14.2f}{:^14.2f}".format(shape, sideSquare, areaSquare, perimSquare))
elif (shape == "hexagon" or "Hexagon"):
    sideHex = float(input("Please provide the side length: "))
    areaHex = (3 * math.pi(3) * sideHex ** 2) / 2
    perimHex = 6 * areaHex
    print("{:^14}{:^14}{:^14}{:^14}".format("Shape", "Value", "Area", "Perimeter"))
    print("{:^14}{:^14.2f}{:^14.2f}{:^14.2f}".format(shape, sideHex, areaHex, perimHex))
else:
    print("I don't have the formulas for a {}.".format(shape))
```

When finding the area and perimeter for the circle, everything works just fine, but when it comes down to the square and hexagon I'm not getting the correct output. What is being output:

```
   Shape         Value          Area       Perimeter   
    square         3.75         44.18         23.56
```

What should be getting output:

```
   Shape         Value          Area       Perimeter   
    square         3.75         14.06         15.00
```

I initially thought that the problem might have been the way I was using the values. I had initially set it up as one circumference/side length value for all of the shapes, then I tried to find a different formula but that still didn't seem to work. Anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Please check the formulae of Perimeter of Square and Hexagon and fix your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to find the problem and fix the issue. I had my formulas for square and hexagon incorrect which is why the outputs were much higher. Formulas should have been

```
areaSquare = (sideSquare)**2
perimSquare = (sideSquare)*4
```

and

```
areaHex = (3 * math.sqrt(3) * sideHex ** 2) / 2
perimHex = 6 * sideHex
```

also did what Will Da Silva said and added

```
if shape == "circle" or shape == "Circle":
```

instead of what I had previously

Answer (score 1):

```
if (shape == "circle" or "Circle"):
```

This condition is always true, as `"Circle"` is truthy. The statement can be broken down into `shape == "circle"` or `"Circle"`. Regardless of the truth value of the first part, the second part is a string with length greater than 0, which is truthy.

Instead, use:

```
if shape == "circle" or shape == "Circle":
```

or:

```
if shape in {"circle", "Circle"}:
```

or, my preferred approach here:

```
if shape.lower() == "circle":
```

The same change will have to be made to your other if conditions.

Comment: this fixed some of the issues and I also managed to fix some of them myself a bit but I'm still having a problem with the output for the hexagon but I think its cause I used the incorrect formulas for the shapes... oops.